# How do you load an embedded icon from an exe file with PyWin32?

Tags: python, icons, exe, pywin32

I have an exe file generated with py2exe. In the setup.py I specify an icon to be embedded in the exe:

```
windows=[{'script': 'my_script.py','icon_resources': [(0, 'my_icon.ico')], ...
```

I tried loading the icon using:

```
hinst = win32api.GetModuleHandle(None)
hicon = win32gui.LoadImage(hinst, 0, win32con.IMAGE_ICON, 0, 0, win32con.LR_DEFAULTSIZE)
```

But this produces an (very unspecific) error:
**pywintypes.error: (0, 'LoadImage', 'No error message is available')**

If I try specifying 0 as a string

```
hicon = win32gui.LoadImage(hinst, '0', win32con.IMAGE_ICON, 0, 0, win32con.LR_DEFAULTSIZE)
```

then I get the error:
**pywintypes.error: (1813, 'LoadImage', 'The specified resource type cannot be found in the image file.')**

So, what's the correct method/syntax to load the icon?
*Also please notice that I don't use any GUI toolkit - just the Windows API via PyWin32.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@efotinis: You're right.

Here is a workaround until py2exe gets fixed and you don't want to include the same icon twice:

```
hicon = win32gui.CreateIconFromResource(win32api.LoadResource(None, win32con.RT_ICON, 1), True)
```

Be aware that **1** is not the ID you gave the icon in setup.py (which is the icon group ID), but the resource ID *automatically* assigned by py2exe to each icon in each icon group. At least that's how I understand it.

If you want to create an icon with a specified size (as CreateIconFromResource uses the system default icon size), you need to use CreateIconFromResourceEx, which isn't available via PyWin32:

```
icon_res = win32api.LoadResource(None, win32con.RT_ICON, 1)
hicon = ctypes.windll.user32.CreateIconFromResourceEx(icon_res, len(icon_res), True,
    0x00030000, 16, 16, win32con.LR_DEFAULTCOLOR)
```

Comment: Ah, yes. I forgot about that. Nice catch.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using wxPython, you can use the following simple code:

```
wx.Icon(sys.argv[0], wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ICO)
```

I usually have code that checks whether it's running from an EXE or not, and acts accordingly:

```
def get_app_icon():
    if hasattr(sys, "frozen") and getattr(sys, "frozen") == "windows_exe":
        return wx.Icon(sys.argv[0], wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ICO)
    else:
        return wx.Icon("gfx/myapp.ico", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ICO)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, well... I installed py2exe and I think it's a bug. In py2exe_util.c they should init `rt_icon_id` to 1 instead of 0. The way it is now, it's impossible to load the first format of the first icon using LoadIcon/LoadImage.

I'll notify the developers about this if it's not already a known issue.

A workaround, in the meantime, would be to include the same icon twice in your setup.py:

```
'icon_resources': [(1, 'my_icon.ico'), (2, 'my_icon.ico')]
```

You can load the second one, while Windows will use the first one as the shell icon. Remember to use non-zero IDs though. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should set the icon ID to something other than 0:

```
'icon_resources': [(42, 'my_icon.ico')]
```

Windows resource IDs must be between 1 and 32767.